# How to identify workstation/process in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, pid

My desktop app will be running simultaneously on multiple Windows workstations in a network. The app needs to give itself an ID that uniquely identifies itself amongst other instances of the app running on other workstations in the network.

What should be used to identify each instance of the app?  Should I use a combination of machine name and process ID?  Are these values accessible from the app if it is running with non-administrative priviliges?

Comment: Process.GetProcesses(machineName) gets all processes for a target machine but a non administrative application can read only processes for its user and your first problem is how to know WHICH machines are on-line on the network. For the other question: **yes**, machine name and process ID are enough to uniquely identify the application within an INTRANET (not INTERNET).

Comment: @DaniloVulović: the only apps are my one app - see my edit of the question.

Comment: @Adriano: I just need the app to provide an ID for a database table that I can be sure is unique on the network and the machine. Will non-admin priviliges allow getting machine name and process ID values?

Comment: Updated my comment. If you're inside an Intranet then yes, it's unique  for each session (process ID is unique system wide and machine name can't be changed without a reboot).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure they have a unique ID then use a GUID, which you could generate when the app starts and report back to whatever manages it.

You won't need admin rights and it eliminates the possibility of a clash of computer names, depending on how the network is setup.

Answer (score 0):

permissions can be limited so that .net cannot access the machine name depending on security settings on the machine for .net

Comment: Is there any issue with getting the `Environment.MachineName` value when the app is run under restricted priviliges?

Comment: -1 User name is useless, and a static field won't prevent the application to run multiple instances...

Comment: CJ7 Environment.Machine name need some permissions (environment variables) but they should be provided for partial trust.